# Using awk or cut command to get CPU percentage

Tags: linux, cpu, php, awk

I am trying to execute a Linux command through a PHP script to get the CPU percentage for each core:

… with `cut`:

```
 $output = null;
 passthru("mpstat -P ALL | grep 0 | tr -s ' ' | cut -d ' ' -f 4", $output);
 echo "$output <br>";
```

… with `awk`:

```
$output = null;
passthru("mpstat -P ALL | grep 0 | tr -s ' ' | awk '{print $4}'", $output);
echo "$output <br>";
```

with the two statements the output is:

```
the name of my server 2.19 2.21 2.30 2.26 2.22 2.20 2.14 2.09 2.07 0
```

My server has an 8 core CPU and I want to use the output directly to Google charts, so I need just the CPU Percentage for 8 cores, without the server name.

Can help me with this issue?

Comment: So what is your problem? Using `echo(implode("\n", $output)[1]);` does  what you need?

Comment: thank you , but it still give me (the server name) before the numbers

Comment: If the server name always has the same length you can use `cut' to remove the first part.

Comment: thanks but the server name is not always the same , i want to get just the numbers in `awk` or `cut` command ?

Comment: @MohammedALJakry Can you use some paste service to provide the output of `mpstat -P ALL`? Executing exactly the same commands as you I don't get my host name on the output. I got the following (4 cores): ` 05/23/2013 %usr 6.71 8.05 7.45 5.87 5.48`.

Comment: Linux 3.2.0-29-generic (h-cache52)     05/23/2013      _x86_64_        (8 CPU)
09:41:01 PM  CPU    %usr   %nice    %sys %iowait    %irq   %soft  %steal  %guest   %idle
the statute for each core ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am echoing the string because my system's `mpstat` is different from what you show in your question but it should work if your output is what you have posted.

```
<?
$string="the name of my server 2.19 2.21 2.30 2.26 2.22 2.20 2.14 2.09 2.07 0";
$output=system("echo $string | perl -ne '/^.+?\s+([\d\. ]+)/; print \"$1\"'");
echo "$output <br>";
?>
```

The Perl script is just looking for the longest stretch of digits, decimal points and spaces (`[\d\. ]+`) and printing it, that should separate server names from the data with arbitrary server names. It will fail if your server's name ends with a number, something like `foo bar 12`. It will not treat the `12` as part of the server's name but as part of the data.

If your server names never contain spaces (which I assume they don't) you can use this `gawk` version if you prefer:

```
<?
$string="thenameofmyserver 2.19 2.21 2.30 2.26 2.22 2.20 2.14 2.09 2.07 0";
$output=system("echo $string | gawk '{for(i=2; i<=NF; i++){printf \"%s \",$(i)}}'");
echo "$output <br>";
?>
```